# sub-domain on plesk : page not found

Tags: apache, apache2, subdomain, plesk

I have a problem with creating a sub-domain on plesk panel.So I created it correctly,also I check "file manager" and I find that the folder with the name of my subdomain created also...

I checked the "DNS setting" and I find DNS of the subdomain created too with the address IP.

But when I preview the link on my browser I have this error:

```
Can not find server example.domain.com because DNS resolution failed...
```

I waited for two days for activation but nothing was change!!

Anyone have an Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Who is maintain DNS for your "domain.com"?

If DNS records of your "domain.com" maintained by some 3rd party domain registrar check that record example.domain.com present in DNS zone in registrar's panel.

If DNS records of your "domain.com" maintained by Plesk server check Plesk DNS by command:

```
nslookup example.domain.com domain.com
```

If you don't know who is your DNS zone maintainer run following command:

```
dig -t NS domain.com
```

Comment: But I don't have ssh acces activated on plesk I can't run the command?I don't have CLI

Comment: What about to ask tech support from your hoster or domain registrar?

Comment: You can run nslookup example.domain.com domain.com from anywhere. From your local machine, for example.

Comment: Ok I run it on my local machine but i have no access to my remote server with ssh!!

Comment: All is ok subdomain configuration, A record and dns seeting because it's created automatically

Comment: I guess really I contact the tech support